# How to add views in relative layout programatically 

Tags: android

I already have a `relative_layout.xml` and it contains sub layouts. Now I've to add  layout into in to one of the sub relative layout insite that `relative_layout.xml`. Could you please tell me how to achieve it programatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is an example it will help you

```
        RelativeLayout child_layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relative_layout_id);
        CheckBox cb = new CheckBox(getApplicationContext());
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                                                         RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
        child_layout.addView(cb, lp);
```

What i am doing is i am fetching relative layout using findviewbyid and then creating checkbox. Then i am creating layout params add checkbox on relative layout according to that layout param.
Hope it will help you..

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly. But how could I change the width and height of that layout, say 200dp*100dp.

Comment: Which layout you are talking about on which you are adding that layout or some other.. simply just create a layout param and where you are giving RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT instead of that give your length and width. If that layout is already attacthed with some other parent layout then use layout_name.SetLayoutParam(lp) this will set length and width of layout_name. If that view is not attached any where or you want to add then use addView.

Answer (score 0):

create view first by code and then add it to the desired layout

if you want to add button to your sub_layout

```
RelativeLayout sub_layout = (RelativeLayout )findViewById(R.id.sub);
Button yourButton = new Button(this);  
sub_layout.addView(yourButton);
```

Comment: There is an error in your code, add should be addView

Answer (score 0):

RelativeLayout sub_layout1 = (LinearLayout )findViewById(R.id.lyt_sub1);

sub_layout1.addView(new_layout);